# Задача на поиск максимальной суммы подмассива (5 kyu)

Tags: python

вот условия:

Задача о максимальной сумме подмассива состоит в нахождении максимальной суммы непрерывной подпоследовательности в массиве или списке целых чисел:

- max_sequence([-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4])
- should be 6: [4, -1, 2, 1]

Простой случай — это когда список состоит только из положительных чисел, а максимальная сумма — это сумма всего массива. Если список состоит только из отрицательных чисел, вместо этого верните 0.

Пустой список считается имеющим нулевую наибольшую сумму. Обратите внимание, что пустой список или массив также является допустимым подсписком/подмассивом.

вот мой код:

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        max_num = arr[0]
        c1, c2 = 0, 0
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            for j in range(len(arr)):
                if sum(arr[c1:c2]) > max_num:
                    max_num = sum(arr[c1:c2])
                c1 += 1
                c2 += 1
            c1 = 0
            c2 = i
    return max_num
```

решение с использованием алгоритма Kadane's Algorithm:

```
def max_sequence(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        maxim = 0
        maxim2 = 0
        for i in (arr):
            maxim = maxim + i
            maxim = max(maxim, 0)
            maxim2 = max(maxim, maxim2)
    return maxim2
```

так как на валидатор с codewars не пускает мое 1е решение из 59 случаев 1 случай оказывается не верным и узнать на чем проваливается тест не предоставляеться возможным. Где ошибка в моей 1й реализации?

Comment: первый вариант работает за O(n^2) вполне возможно что просто не прошёл перфоманс тест. Да и в целом он странный, зачем нужны c1 и c2 если i и j ту же самую роль может выполнить.

Comment: Проблема для меня была скорее в неполном понимании задачи... так как не требуется получить на выходе результат подмассива, точнее поиск того самого массива. Но если бы и требовалось то каким алгоритмом нужно воспользоваться? или использовать 2й алгоритм но уже с взятием индексов с массива чисел?

Answer (score 1):

разобрался на другом примере:

**Временная сложность: O(N), где N — размер массива.**

```
    def maximumSubarraySum(arr):
       n = len(arr)
       maxSum = -1e8
       currSum = 0

       for i in range(0, n):
           currSum = currSum + arr[i]
           if(currSum > maxSum):
               maxSum = currSum
           if(currSum < 0):
               currSum = 0
      
       return maxSum

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Your code goes here
    print(maximumSubarraySum([1, 3, 8, -2, 6, -8, 5]))
```